# Reverse DNS Lookup on ubuntu inside virtualbox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh, dns

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 inside virtualbox on win7 using NAT for networking.
I had to run the command :

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Ubuntu" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Which basically tells the guest to use hosts' dns server for resolving hostnames.

I can use internet seamlessly after this, including (almost ) everything on my office's corporate network under vpn.

I can resolve the ip address for any hostname :

```
$ host xxx.company.com.
xxx.company.com has address 100.100.64.13
```

But i cannot resolve a hostname using an ip address inside the company network. ( which is causing some of the functionalities, like ssh etc to not work ) :

```
$ host 100.100.64.13
Host 12.64.121.100.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ nslookup 100.100.64.13
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find 12.64.121.100.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

However, I have nslookup working on the host.

```
C:\Users\gautam>nslookup 100.121.64.13
Server:  xxx.compan.com
Address:  x.x.x.x

Name:    the.correct.host.name
Address:  100.100.64.13
```

Can anyone help me getting the reverse dns lookup working inside the guest OS ?

Comment: Any help ? I'm still facing this issue and would appreciate any directions. Needless to mention further that everything works perfectly in bridge mode. But I need to make it work over NAT to be able to work over wireless. I'm wondering if the following comamnd works for both forward and reverse dns lookups : 
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Ubuntu" --natdnshostresolver1 on ??
Is there another command like : 
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Ubuntu" --natreversednshostresolver1 on

Comment: Is manually specifying the DNS server to use an option for you (to use an upstream server instead of VBox's which is apparently lacking)?